# Как можно считать была ли нажата клавиша ESC?

Tags: python, tkinter

Делаю прогу одну, суть в том, что когда вводишь пароль 3 раза неверно, то должны создаваться окна (TopLevel) в случайных местах(с этим мне уже помогли на форуме), но проблема в том, что это нужно зациклить и отменить их создание при нажатии клавиши ESC. Как это можно реализовать и как считать нажатие клавиши?
Вот кусок кода.

```
k = 0
def sravnenie():
    global k

    
    a = e1.get()
    
    if a == itog:
        print('Пароль верный!')
        new_window1 = Toplevel(root)
        new_window1.geometry('200x200')
        l3 = Label(new_window1, text = 'Успех!', borderwidth = 5, font = 'TimesNewRoman 30')
        l3.place(x=50, y=50)
        
    else:
        l4 = Label(text = 'Неверный пароль!')
        l4.place(x=120, y=50)
        k += 1
        print(k)
        if k >= 3:
            print(k,"Достигнут лимит!")
            #new_window2 = Toplevel(root)
            #new_window2.geometry('200x200')
            #l4 = Label(new_window2, text = 'Провал!', borderwidth = 5, font = 'TimesNewRoman 30')
            #l4.place(x=30, y=50)
            show_window()
            

#окно в случайном месте
def show_window():
    window1 = Toplevel(root)
    w1_width, w1_height = 300, 100  # длина и ширина создаваемого окна
    print(d_width - w1_width, d_height - w1_height)
    # координаты верхнего левого угла создаваемого окна, определяющиеся 
    # рандомно:
    w1_x, w1_y = random.randint(0, d_width - w1_width), \
                 random.randint(0, d_height - w1_height)
    window1.geometry(f"{w1_width}x{w1_height}+{w1_x}+{w1_y}")
    window1.title('Окно в случайном месте')
    chek_key_pressed()

def chek_key_pressed():
    if #не нажата ESC: то show_window()

#для окна    
d_width, d_height = [root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467285/how-do-i-bind-the-escape-key-to-close-this-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
from tkinter import *


# окно в случайном месте
def show_window():
    global random_windows
    window1 = Toplevel(root)
    w1_width, w1_height = 300, 100  # длина и ширина создаваемого окна
    # координаты верхнего левого угла создаваемого окна, определяющиеся
    # рандомно:
    w1_x, w1_y = random.randint(0, d_width - w1_width), \
                 random.randint(0, d_height - w1_height)
    window1.geometry(f"{w1_width}x{w1_height}+{w1_x}+{w1_y}")
    window1.title('Окно в случайном месте')
    random_windows.append(window1)  # добавляем в список
    # после создания рандомного окна делаем активным основное окно (root), 
    # чтобы в нем принимать нажатие клавиш:
    root.focus()


def destroy_random_windows(*args, **kwargs):
    for i in random_windows:  # для окна в списке рандом. окон
        i.destroy()  # закрываем окно


# для окна
root = Tk()
# при нажатии Esc вызываем функцию destroy_random_windows:
root.bind('<Escape>', destroy_random_windows)
d_width, d_height = [root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()]
random_windows = []  # список для создаваемых в show_window() окон
# моделируем ситуацию, когда создано 3 рандомных окна:
show_window()
show_window()
show_window()
root.mainloop()
```